# Generator expression in class not producing output I expect

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, generator

I'd like to use some generator expressions as attributes for some expensive computation of data. If possible I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.evens = (i for i in self.data if i % 2 == 0)

def __main__():
    t = Test()
    t.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

    for item in t.evens:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

I would liked to have seen this print out `2 4 6 8` but this gives no output. Have I made some sort of simple mistake here?

Is what I am trying to do here possible or will I need to use `yield` to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the other answers have correctly diagnosed the error (that your `evens` generator is being initialized with the original empty `data` list), I think the suggestion to set a value for `data` still won't do what you want.

Currently you can only iterate over `evens` once, and after you do it will have been consumed. What I think you want is for `evens` to always be accessible as a generator of the even values of whatever the current `data` value has. The way to do that is to make it a `property`, with a function that returns the generator each time it is called:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    @property
    def evens(self):
        return (i for i in self.data if i % 2 == 0)
```

Usage:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(t.evens)
[2, 4, 6]
>>> list(t.evens) # works more than once
[2, 4, 5]
>>> t.data = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
>>> list(t.evens)
[10, 20, 30]
```

If you needed a more complicated generator, you could use `yield` in the function, rather than returning a generator object, but a generator expression works easily enough for getting even values.

Answer (score 2):

The generator expression `self.evens = (i for i in self.data if i % 2 == 0)` is only called when you first initialize the instance of the class. It is initialized with `self.data` as an empty list, therefore the generator expression containing all the even numbers in that list is empty. When you set `data` again, the generator expression line is not called again.

Changing your code to this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    self.evens = (i for i in self.data if i % 2 == 0)

def main():
    t = Test([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

    for item in t.evens:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

should have the effect you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The generator defers the creation of its values, but it uses the value of `self.data` as it exists when the generator is created. It doesn't defer that part as you seem to expect, by using the *name* `self.data` later.

This is easily demonstrated:

```
>>> dat = range(10,20)
>>> evens = (i for i in dat if i % 2 == 0)
>>> dat = range(10)
>>> list(evens)
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> evens = (i for i in dat if i % 2 == 0)
>>> list(evens)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

You need to re-create the generator whenever `data` is changed, and initially it probably makes sense to make `data` a parameter of your `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your not passing data into the class!

The `__init__` is called when the class is created and `self.data` is an empty list when the class is created therefore when you try to: `[i for i in self.data if i % 2 == 0]` you iterate over an empty list!

Try this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.evens = [i for i in self.data if i % 2 == 0]

def __main__():
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    t = Test(x)


    for item in t.evens:
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your generator expression is initialized with an empty `data`. Pass `data` to the `__init__` method instead:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.evens = (i for i in data if i % 2 == 0)


def __main__():
    t = Test(data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

    for item in t.evens:
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

prints:

```
2
4
6
8
```